# Repeat numbers using itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I was learning itertools and encountered an interesting problem.

How to get the following result?

```
nums = [1,2,3,4]
# logic:  i+1 th number is repeated i times.
          2 is repeated 1 times and 4 is repeated 3 times.

required = [2,4,4,4]
```

## My attempt

```
import itertools

nums = [1,2,3,4]
nums[::2]  # [1,3]
nums[1::2] # [2,4]
              * 2 is repeated 1 times
                * 4 is repeated 3 times and makes [2,4,4,4]

list(itertools.starmap(itertools.repeat, zip(nums[::2],nums[1::2])))

Gives,
[repeat(1, 2), repeat(3, 4)]

How to get:
required = [2,4,4,4]
```

## Required

```
From: [1,2,3,4]
To:   [2,4,4,4]

We can use itertools, list comp and numpy.
With emphasis on itertools, since I am learning itertools functions
such as repeat, starmap and so on.
```

Comment: The required output and the textual description don't seem to match (why doesn't ***3*** appear in the former?).

Comment: one uses `n` for the total number of items in a sequence. please use `i` for *every* or *any*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`repeat` creates an iterable object, so you need to chain those iterators together, and before creating a list by iterating over the result. (You also need to swap the arguments to `zip`)

```
>>> from itertools import starmap, repeat, chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, zip(nums[1::2], nums[::2]))))
[2, 4, 4, 4]
```

Actually, you don't need either `starmap` or `zip`; `map` can apply a multi parameter function to multiple iterators, taking one argument from each iterator per call.

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, nums[1::2], nums[::2])))
[2, 4, 4, 4]
```

Going one step further into `itertools` land, you can use `tee` and `islice` to avoid having to create two temporary lists by slicing `nums` (though doing so in one line gets messy):

```
>>> from itertools import tee, islice
>>> t1, t2 = tee(nums)
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, islice(t1, 1, None, 2), islice(t2, None, None, 2))))
[2, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

you don't need itertools for that.  A list comprehension and zip are sufficient:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4]

rnums = [ rn for r,n in zip(nums[::2],nums[1::2]) for rn in r*[n] ]

print(rnums) # [2, 4, 4, 4]
```

[EDIT]: using itertools:

```
nums = [*chain(*map(repeat,zip(nums[::2],nums[1::2])))]
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this, but I was wondering if there was way of doing using itertools.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go simple, no itertools, no list comprehension, it can be done very easily like this:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4]
ans = []
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if i%2: # odd index
        ans += [ nums[i] ] * nums[i-1]
```

## Using list comp

```
sum(([nums[i+1]]*nums[i] for i in range(0, len(nums), 2)), [])
```